# How to detect whether the phone connected to android auto

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager, android-auto

I'm developing an audio player application, and I need to determine when the user's device is connected to Android Auto.

The application features an alarm, and I want to make sure it doesn't go off while the user is driving.

To determine whether my music-service (`MediaBrowserService`) works, I can use some flags in onCreate and onDestroy, or register [reciver for "com.google.android.gms.car.media.STATUS" action](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/auto/audio/index.html#isconnected) - but it's a bad idea because alarm clock can trigger in any time. And not only when my music-service is running.

For alarm and I use `AlarmManager` and pending intent.

Maybe someone faced with similar problems?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 6):

You can check UIMode like in google example:

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-UniversalMusicPlayer/blob/master/mobile/src/main/java/com/example/android/uamp/utils/CarHelper.java#L106

```
public static boolean isCarUiMode(Context c) {
    UiModeManager uiModeManager = (UiModeManager) c.getSystemService(Context.UI_MODE_SERVICE);
    if (uiModeManager.getCurrentModeType() == Configuration.UI_MODE_TYPE_CAR) {
        LogHelper.d(TAG, "Running in Car mode");
        return true;
    } else {
        LogHelper.d(TAG, "Running on a non-Car mode");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then before run alarm check `isCarUiMode` result

Comment: has anyone tested this? i'm always getting 'false'.

Comment: I've tried this, and it seems to work if you loop the check periodically in the background.  Doing so allows the app to trap cases where the `com.google.android.gms.car.media.STATUS` event doesn't trigger when it logically seems like it should (in my case, I would only get `com.google.android.gms.car.media.STATUS` when manually navigating to the 'Media' section of Android Auto, which is a user-initiated action occurring _well after_ Auto actually connects).  Doesn't seem ideal, but was sufficient to pass Google's review process.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned you can register a reciever for ["com.google.android.gms.car.media.STATUS"](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/auto/audio/index.html#isconnected) and save the status into e.g. [shared preferences](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html).

When the application wants to display the alarm, it can check the saved status. If status is connected do not show the alram, otherwise show it.

Something like:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
     String status = intent.getStringExtra("media_connection_status");
     boolean isConnectedToCar = "media_connected".equals(status);
     SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences(
            "myprefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
     SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPrefs.edit();
     editor.putBoolean("isConnected", isConnectedToCar);
     editor.commit();
}
```

And when the alarm is triggered:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences(
            "myprefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
boolean isConnected = sharedPref.getBoolean("isConnected", false);
if (!isConnected) {
   // Alarm
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Of course I understand that. And that's what I did. If my service is running, I can easily catch it and do not show any alarms. But that is **absolutely** not solve the problem. This Broadcast Receiver is triggered **only** when started my service.
This receiver **does not notify** that you connect phone to the auto android device, it comes just when your service started.
But service will start only if the **user launches** the application on android-auto device. But what if phone is connected to the android auto, but user does not launch the application? Is it possible? Certainly possible.

Comment: So the Service will not start, Broadcast will not come, and in the alarm time I wrong to think that the phone is not connected to the android auto.  Thet's a problem.  That's why I need a way to to know **not about the launch of my service**, I need a way to know about connecting the phone to the auto-android device.

Comment: In your service, what do you return in your onStartCommand method? Have you tried to return Service#START_STICKY or Service#START_REDELIVER_INTENT?

Comment: For android auto it does not matter. I do not override this method. When you start the service (MediaBrowserService) onStartCommand method is not called (a few minutes ago I specifically override this method, and run the application, this method has not been called). Earlier, I wrote that android auto absolutely not obliged to run my service when the phone is connected to the auto android device and that is normal.