# How to detect if Android Head Unit is connected to Android Auto

Tags: android, android-auto, android-automotive

I am making a media app for Android Head Unit that should check the connection if the car is connected to an Android Auto. Is there a way for my app to detect if it is is connected to Android Auto?

Is it possible for Auto media apps to detec Android Auto connection status via a BroadcastReceiver registered. I already tried to create a BroadCastReceiver with `androidx.car.app.connection.action.CAR_CONNECTION_UPDATED` just like this [text](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72881651) but it didnt work.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`CarConnection` API](https://developer.android.com/training/cars/apps#car-connection) from the [`androidx.car.app:app` module](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/car-app), which handles registering the broadcast receiver for you [[source code](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:car/app/app/src/main/java/androidx/car/app/connection/CarConnection.java?q=CarConnection.java)].