# Is there a way that apps can get notified when Android Auto is connected?

Tags: android, android-auto

Is it possible to get notified (e.g. through a broadcast receiver) when the phone gets connected to Android Auto? We know that it is possible through the [CarConnection API](https://developer.android.com/training/cars/apps#car-connection) however it requires us to have the activity or at least a service constantly running as the subscription requires a context.

So basically we are looking for something like a [Manifest-declared broadcast receiver](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts) so that our app doesn't need to run in the background. Unfortunately they're not available since Android 8 anymore (in case they're [not exempt from the rule](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions)). We already considered using a Bluetooth / USB Broadcast receiver to detect if Android-Auto is connected but that seems way to unstable and hacky.

Background: We want to extend our [Weather and Radar](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.wetteronline.wetterapp&hl=en&gl=US) app so that as soon as the driver connects his phone we check for severe weather warnings in his area.

Answer (score 0):

I believe `CarConnection` is the way to achieve this, since it includes a broadcast receiver under the hood. If you don't want to use that API, probably you could create your own broadcast receiver like it is done in [CarConnectionTypeLiveData](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:car/app/app/src/main/java/androidx/car/app/connection/CarConnectionTypeLiveData.java).

By the way, there is a similar question here: [How to detect if Android Head Unit is connected to Android Auto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76737443/how-to-detect-if-android-head-unit-is-connected-to-android-auto)

Comment: My question is different as I am looking for a solution that doesn't require the app to run in the background. Your solution requires that the app is constantly running (e.g. as a background service). The solution I'm looking / asking for would be a manifest declared receiver that would use an implicit broadcast that is exempt from the background execution limits: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions