# Detect if my phone is connected to my car

Tags: android, angular

I am developing an application with Angular 8 and I need to know when my phone is connected to my car.
I have found this answer for android:
[How to detect whether the phone connected to android auto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36293866/how-to-detect-whether-the-phone-connected-to-android-auto/41931372#41931372)
There are also these packages (device, device-detector-js and obd2) but I don't know if they are correct.
Does anyone have information about how to detect said connection from Angular?